# JavaScript as a "service" on phones

Tags: javascript, android, ios, windows-phone-7

I am putting together project plan and have come across a silly question.

For right now, the plan is for the project to be a web only app. Meaning I am not planning on making native clients. Someday possibly.

I want to know the feasibility of using JS on a web page as a "service" so to speak. If the user logs in and the JS starts up, how long will it be allowed to run if the user changes to a different app or turns their screen off?

I have done some testing but I can not confirm what I am seeing on the web. I am hoping to do that here.

Test: Join jabbR.net. Leave browser. turn screen off.

iOS: User got disco'ed after 15ish mins. 
Android: User still connected after 40ish mins 
WinPhone: No idea, don't have access to one

What I assume happens is the OS will suspend the browser as some point in time. I am just looking for what the criteria is for an app to be suspended or if the app will keep it self open because it is doing something (unlikely).

NOTE: I know a native service would be best case here. The reason I am asking is I am seeing if ideas I have for the app are feasible with the browser only.

Comment: It all comes down to memorymanagement. For all I read/heard is that as soon as the OS sees the need to clear up some memory it will pick any app that hasn't been used recently, or if it really needs a lot of memory, all apps. If that happens 40mins after the closing of the app or four seconds all comes down to the devices usage.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer that is my assumption as well.